# tHDFSRename: file does not exist or no unique matching for current filemask

Tags: hdfs, talend

I am trying to rename a file on HDFS using Talend's tHDFSRename component. It fails with the error: "file does not exist or no unique matching for current filemask". After a lot of debugging, found that the problem is related to the filename containing a plus (+) sign. Is there any way out?

Comment: try escaping it with a backslash  \.  If that doesn't work try a double backslash.  That typically works for me.

Comment: I have done that but it did not work: Got an error that printed the patname split at plus. The issue is with the tHDFSRename component that takes a filemask and not simply a pathname as input.

Comment: ok, then instead of trying to fix the  tHDFSRename component, use a tFileCopy and rename it first.  I just tried it and it works fine even with a plus sign in the name.  In the basic settings if you check off "Rename" and "Remove source file" it will replace your existing file with the new file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using tHDFSCopy component.